# Apply multiple classes for single div

Tags: html, css

I have created a submenu, I want the background color of the divs to change depending on what page the submenu is loaded.

first example (with code working for one page):

HTML

```
<div class="tablecontainer">
    <div class="left">
        <p><a href="#">Link1</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p><a href="#">Link2</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <p><a href="#">Link3</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p><a href="#">Link4</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <p><a href="#">Link5</a></p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tablecontainter{
    width:100%  
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    background-color: #660066;
    text-align: center; 
}
.left a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.right {
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    background-color: #660066;
    text-align: center; 
}
.right a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.cell{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    background-color: #660066;
    text-align: center;
}
.cell a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

[jsfiddle: example1](http://jsfiddle.net/lupis/FRHT5/)

and the second example

HTML

```
<div class="tablecontainer">
    <div class="left leftYH">
        <p><a href="#">Link1</a></p>
    </div>
        <div class="right rightYH">
        <p><a href="#">Link2</a></p>
    </div><div class="left leftYH">
        <p><a href="#">Link3</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="right rightYH">
        <p><a href="#">Link4</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell cellYH">
        <p><a href="#">Link5</a></p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tablecontainter{
    width:100%;
}
.left{
    float: left;
}
.left, .right{  
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
.cell{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    text-align: center; 
}
.left a, .right a, .cell a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.leftYh, .rightYh, cellYH{
    background-color: #660066;  
}
```

[jsfiddle: example2](http://jsfiddle.net/lupis/z4DxK/)

where I have grouped all class with similar attributes and others where the attributes are unique. But this code is not at all working.
Any clue anyone where I screwed up?

Thanks

Comment: Post your code here please.

Comment: you could use scripting to reassign the class on the fly based on what I read here.. hard to help with no code though...

Comment: someone tried to edit the code into the question, and a mod rejected it.  Why?

Comment: You cant link to the fiddle without the code present.. don't bend the rules, follow them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your css class names are wrong, they should be `.leftYH, .rightYH, .cellYH` you had lower case h's

**UPDATE**

You also need to apply `width:50%` only to your `.left` class, and you were missing a `.` for `cellYH`

Check out the example below

css

```
.tablecontainer{
    width:100%
}
.left, .right{
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
.left{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.cell{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    text-align: center; 
}
.left a, .right a, .cell a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.leftYH, .rightYH, .cellYH{
    background-color: #660066;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z4DxK/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats what happens when you are sitting late at night with a idea :P

Answer (score 0):

Change line 37 to `.leftYH, .rightYH, .cellYH` (lower case H and missing `.` before cellYH).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to inherit from more then one CSS class~

- Multi class styles: this states that all classes gain the following attributes

  ```
   left a, .right a, .cell a{
         ....

   }
  ```
- multi class elements: you can apply more then one class to any html tag like to

  ```
  <a class="left right cell>
  ```